# How to apply Jquery slideToggle() to multiple divs with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main_box").click(function() {
    $(".sliding_box").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
div.main_box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
div.sliding_box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main_box"></div>
  <div class="sliding_box"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main_box"></div>
  <div class="sliding_box"></div>
</div>
```

When I click on "main_box" div, both the "sliding_box" divs go up. I want only the first "sliding_box" div go up after clicking on first "main_box" div.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to target `$(this).siblings('.sliding_box')` instead of `$(".sliding_box")`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main_box").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.sliding_box').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
div.main_box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
div.sliding_box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main_box"></div>
  <div class="sliding_box"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main_box"></div>
  <div class="sliding_box"></div>
</div>
```

Reference: [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)