# How to Apply jQuery SlideToggle to foreach loop?

Tags: jquery, magento, foreach, categories, slidetoggle

I'm trying to apply SlideToggle for the categories list foreach Loop. I've tried various techniques but all goes in vain. I've found **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955618/how-to-apply-jquery-slidetoggle-to-multiple-divs-with-same-class)** useful and similar to what I need but this again doesn't work. Any idea why it is not working?

```
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
        <script> 
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".main_box").click(function() {
            $(this).siblings('.sliding_box').slideToggle();
      });
    });
        </script>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="main_box">
                <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>                 
            </div>  
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
        <div class="sliding_box">   
            <ul class="listx" style="display:none;">
                <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                    <li class="item" >
                        <a style="color:orange;" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                            <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <?php endif; ?> 
        </div>
        <?php  endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And you did include the jQuery library above that code ?

Comment: Yes as it is magento, there are already jQuery library in it. Well, I was getting jQuery Uncaught TypeError. Now I solved by changing $(document).ready(function () to jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should must be working but thing is it's inner content ul is hidden with display none css property. Better can you provide jsFiddle with html code generated from here. Or atlease html.

here is your code in working condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".main_box").click(function() {
            $(this).siblings('.sliding_box').slideToggle();
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="main_box">
                Name here             
            </div>  
        <div class="sliding_box">   
            <ul class="listx">
                    <li class="item" >
                        <a style="color:orange;" href="#">
                            link
                        </a>
                    </li>
              <li class="item" >
                        <a style="color:orange;" href="#">
                            link
                        </a>
                    </li>
              <li class="item" >
                        <a style="color:orange;" href="#">
                            link
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```